# How to add a UNC URL to a MediaWiki page

Tags: url, links, mediawiki

In a MediaWiki page, I'd like to add an URL to a file on a file server. The path is an UNC one(`\\fileserver\project\...\SPECIAL.ext`), and I already have tried following "path link":

```
file:////fileserver/projet/.../SPECIAL.ext
```

I know this is correct: when I enter this location in the address bar of my internet browser, automatically the file gets downloaded.

However, when I put the following line in a Mediawiki page, it doesn't work:

```
[file:////fileserver/projet/.../SPECIAL.ext]
```

Not working simply means that I just see "[file:...]" on the page (apparently Mediawiki does not understand that the square brackets are used for defining an URL. When I remove the square brackets, still no good result, I just see "file:...").

However, there are some URLs inside my wiki (they just start with `http://`), so I have the impression that my MediaWiki doesn't know that `file://` has a similar meaning than `http://`. How do I configure my MediaWiki for this?

Oh, I prefer solving this issue using a simple configuration, if possible. I'd like to avoid installing extensions.

Comment: It’s not unlikely `file:` URIs are forbidden entirely.

Comment: @DanielB: your comment might mean that I need to use another way to create a "download" link on a MediaWiki page. It's important that it is not a link to a file on the MediaWiki server, but on another one. Do you know another way to do this?

Comment: @DanielB: in the meantime I tried using `http://` instead of `file://`. This works, but `http:////fileserver/projet` gets translated into `fileserver/projet` instead of `\\fileserver\projet`, no matter how many slashes I put (2, 4, 6, ...).

Comment: Nobody knows how to put slashes in front of an UNC path for mediawiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing: It won't work for others.

[image: Wikipedia sandbox error]

Perhaps you could:

1. Try to provide a link to it on the Internet
2. Upload it with Special:Upload if the .ext file format is supported.

Perhaps that's why MW ignores it.

EDIT: To address recent comments, it's possible that MW is not adapted to `file://` at all, though we don't know for sure.

Comment: Your error statement says that links, starting with `file://` point to files on your own computer, but in my case, I'm working with a file server, where everybody has access to, but there is no IIS on that machine, so `http://` does not work. In a first comment on my question, someone mentioned that `file://` URI usage is completely forbidden. Isn't there a way to allow it exceptionally?

Comment: That's probably the case since MW isn't adapted to working with file servers. Wikipedia, the first MW wiki, didn't and won't have to deal with such situations.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a variable in LocalSettings.php called `$wgUrlProtocols`. According to the comment before that variable in [DefaultSettings.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/fdd8f864b84db0f1a35fbc4eb4db6db39f83b7e3/includes/DefaultSettings.php#L4844-L4859), you can add `file://` to it. I think that means links to a file server should then work.

Comment: I'm planning to do this, but once I've finished, is there something I need to restart in order to make this work?

Comment: I believe that adding this entry turns `file://` entries into URLs, which is working fine indeed, but we're not there yet: when I put `file:////fileserver` or `file://\\fileserver` I see he wants to go to `fileserver` (without slashes or backslashes). I also tried replacing the (back)slashes by ´%2f´ or `%5c` (their ASCII codes), but that didn't help either.